# wordpressのカスタムフィールド へ投稿IDを出力させたい

Tags: wordpress

WORDPRESSのadvanced custom fieldでカスタム投稿の入力フォームを作成しています。
１度保存すると、投稿IDが付与されるのですが、その投稿IDを管理画面の投稿入力の画面で、カスタムフィールド内に表示させることはできないでしょうか？

例えば、「投稿ID」（タイプ：テキスト）というフィールドを作成しておいて、投稿画面を作ります。
投稿者が、新規投稿を作成して保存後、次に開いたときには、その中に投稿IDが自動表示されているような形を希望しています。

編集画面のURLを見たら、投稿IDは見れるのですが、できれば、画面内に表示させたいです。

Comment: (回答もついているようですが)念のため確認ですがやりたいことは「投稿編集ページ内に投稿IDを表示する」ではなくて「カスタムフィールドにページIDも入れる」なのですか？

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございます。
ご指摘のように、やりたいことずばりは、投稿編集ページ内に投稿IDを表示する、です。
そこで、なぜ、カスタムフィールド に入れたいかというと、フィールド内に入っている方が投稿IDをコピペで取得することができ、間違いがないかと思ったもので；

任意のIDの投稿だけを一覧にするページを作成しようとしていまして、別のカスタムフィールド で、表示させる投稿のIDをカンマ区切りで入力するフィールドを用意し、そこに編集者がIDをカンマ区切りで入れていったら、そのアーカイブを自動で表示させるようにしようとしています。編集者のスキルがそれほど高くはないので、たくさんある機能の中で、URLからIDを拾ってくれというよりは、管理画面で確認したら、IDが表示されているから、という方が使いやすいと思ったのですが、この表示方法がわからず、頭を悩ませていました。見ていただき、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

フィールド名:'post2id'を作成して置き、テーマのfunctions.phpに以下のコード追加

**動作の説明**
　新規作成時に呼ばれるアクションフック　'admin_head-post-new.php'で
　post_type が 'post'の時に　$post->IDの値を、フィールド名:'post2id'へ保存します。
　また、不用意に追加しないようにupdate_post_metaで上書きしています。

```
function add_meta_id() {
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type === 'post'){
        if(!update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post2id', $post->ID )){
            add_post_meta($post->ID, "post2id", $post->ID);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'add_meta_id' );
```

**本当に、必要なのか精査して使って下さい。**
カスタムフィールド名、post typeは適時変更してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！こちらの通りに、フィールド名とポストタイプを変えて、追加したら、希望した通りに出るようになりました。大変助かりました！！

Answer (score 0):

コメントを読む限り、編集ページ内にメタボックスを出したいだけのようなのでわざわざ無駄なカスタムフィールドが必要とは思えません。(ほんとうに必要なのかってそういう意味では？)

単純に投稿IDを表示するメタボックスを設置するだけであれば例えば以下のような単純なコードを追加するだけで完結します。

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function () {
    add_meta_box( 'example-post-id', '投稿ID', function ( WP_Post $post ) {
        printf( '<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="%d" >', $post->ID );
    } );
}, 'post' );
```

[image]