# カスタムフィールドテンプレートにて入力した値を保存・更新した後に発火し、PHPでロジックをカスタマイズすることは可能でしょうか？

Tags: wordpress

カスタムフィールドテンプレートにて商品情報の入力をするフォームがあります。

入力した時点で、javascriptを用いて、リアルタイムに書き換えをすることもできますが、
今回の要件では、保存・更新ボタンを押し、データが保存する前にサーバーサイドで計算するロジックを計算したいと思っております。

話を単純にするため、今回、サーバーサイドで行いたいロジックは
商品金額と送料を計算し、合計金額というカラムに保存させるという前提で話を進めます。

※この内容でしたら、javascriptでできるかと思いますが、
実際のロジックはもう少し複雑で、商品合計金額をjavascriptで買えてしまうと、
他の値もjavascriptの計算で書き換わってしまうため、
サーバーサイドで処理したいと考えております。

function.php にそのようなロジックを追加したら良いのかと思いますが、
add_actionで上書きするためのメソッドがわからず調べているのですが、上手くヒットせず困っております。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問　”[wordpressのカスタムフィールド へ投稿IDを出力させたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41178/)”の回答とほぼ同じなのですが、下書き保存・公開完了に呼ばれるアクションフック　'admin_head-post.php'を使います。

例、

```
function 関数名() {
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type === 'post'){
        処理
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', '関数名' );
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。類似の質問も確認できました。既に似たような内容がある中、失礼致しました。