# カスタムフィールドの日付でソートさせ、カスタムフィールドに日付の入力がないときは最終更新日でソートする

Tags: php, wordpress

カスタムフィールドの日付でソート、最終更新日でソート、これらを合わせて行いたいと思っています。
カスタムフィールドに日付の入力がないときは、最終更新日をソートに使う日付にしたいと思い、下記のようなコードを途中までこしらえたのですが、ここから先どうすれば`$date`をもとにソートさせることができるのかわかりません。どなたかお分かりになる方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示お願いいたします。

```php
<?php        

if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pdate',true)){
    $date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pdate', true );}
else{
    $date = get_the_modified_date(); }

$paged = (int) get_query_var('paged');
$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date', 
);?>
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/244933

Comment: 参考までに、記事（post）のカスタムフィールドが”data_date”のとき、カスタムフィールド値でソートする場合のget_postsのオプションは
get_posts(array('order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'meta_value','meta_key' => 'data_date'));　となります。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。カスタムフィールドの値を日付データとして、それをもとにソートすることはできるのですが、値がなければ更新日でソートという条件をつけたいと考えています

Comment: カスタムフィールドの値が入力されない時はアクションフックで日時（最終更新日）をセットする様にすると良いかと思います。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41178/wordpress%e3%81%ae%e3%82%ab%e3%82%b9%e3%82%bf%e3%83%a0%e3%83%95%e3%82%a3%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%83%89-%e3%81%b8%e6%8a%95%e7%a8%bfid%e3%82%92%e5%87%ba%e5%8a%9b%e3%81%95%e3%81%9b%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84?rq=1

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど、カスタムフィールドへ値が入ってないなら、最終更新日を自動で入れればいいということですね！ @yyz